# JQuery to put select option text into an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code here, it pulls out the selected option value from a drop-down box named "attribute[466]" then puts that value into an input field with the id of text_qty_

```
jQuery(function($){
   var $idval = $('#text_qty_');
   $('select[name="attribute[466]"]').change(function(){
      $idval.val($(this).val())
   }).triggerHandler('change')
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to get the text from the option selected rather than the value.

As an added challenge the select element that contains the drop-down box has a randomly generated ID attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the selected option and read the text

```
var txt = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVAmW/)

Comment: Thanks, changed what I had to this:                                   $('select[name="attribute[466]"]').on("change", function(){
    var txt = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    var $idval = $('#text_qty_');
    $idval.val(txt)
}).trigger("change");